# Laravel 5 - Route parameter with slash

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem in old laravel 5.0 project route because I need to pass a parameter that sometimes could have a `/`.

I do this:

```
Route::get('/app/budget/search/{text?}/{column}', 'BudgetController@search')->where('text', '(.*)');
```

But doesn't work.
My laravel project version is `5.0` .

Comment: This only works if text is the last parameter, otherwise there is no way to distinct text from column.

Comment: Define 2 routes that would satisfy both conditions.

Comment: You need to write a more complex regex that defines a non-greedy operator or selects captures only 1 slaches.